# PHP nested array list needed

Tags: php, arrays, list, nested

I am trying to loop two values through a foreach.  I found a great example on php.net but when I try to implement it shows as bad code.

```
$array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
];
foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
    echo "A: $a; B: $b\n";
}
```

which is supposed to give you:

```
A: 1; B: 2
A: 3; B: 4
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

For my purposes, I'm trying to do this:

```
$array = [
    [$csal, Salary],
    [$ccar, Car],
];
foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
    if($$a==NULL){$$ap="$b";
}
}
```

which I want to equal

```
 if($csal==NULL){$csal="Salary";
 }
 if($ccar==NULL){$ccarp="Car";
 }
```

I've tried switching out the brackets with ( and no luck.

Comment: what are you trying to do there anyway? putting some default value equivalent? why not put a default value on the assignment right away instead of doing it under the loop

Comment: Because I have to do it several hundred times.

Comment: then you should have prepared for that even before `$csal` and others, where did this hundreds of data came from? maybe post more pertinent code before this array assignment, still unclear why do you have to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
[1, 2],
[3, 4],
];
foreach ($array as list($a, $b)){}
```

in **$array**, you used the wrong syntax to assigned the value also
what you did in **foreach function** is that you assigned the value of array to a function called list() which is wrong...

you need to edit your code like this

```
$array = array(array(1,2),array(3,4));
foreach ($array as $list) { 
   echo "A:$list[0] B:$list[1]";
}
```

hoping this will help...

Comment: How do I do this part of it too:   if($ccar==NULL){$ccarp="Car";
 }.  I was thinking $$list[0]'p' or $$list[0]p or "$$list[0]"p but none of those work.  I basically want to concatonate a letter onto the end of the variable creating a while new one.  But the loop part is working.

Comment: just use one dollar sign and concatenate the string like this  `$list[0].'p'`

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop return, for each row, the key index and the value.

So, in your first example:

```
foreach( $array as list( $a, $b ) )
```

at the first loop `$a` is 0 (the first key) and `$b` is `[1, 2]`, the first sub-array.

You have to use a nested loop:

```
foreach( $array as list( $key, $val ) )
{
    foreach( $val as list( $key1, $val1 ) )
    {
        echo "[$key][$key1]: $val1";
    }
}
```

Or - as I prefer - in the old-fashioned way:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $val )
{
    foreach( $val as $key1 => $val1 )
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Obviously, also your second example has the same misunderstanding.